# self.navigationController pushViewController:SomeViewController animated:YES is not giving the correct view after the orientation changed

Tags: ipad, landscape, pushviewcontroller, device-orientation, popviewcontroller

I'm having an wired issue on my iPad app on home screen, it has four different views on home page cause it has an arabic layout for each portrait and landscape view and I'm drawing each view with code. Each of them contain different layout.
The problem is when i navigate from the portrait home screen to another screen with 
    **[self.navigationController pushViewController:ArticleListsProtrait animated:YES]** code
then rotate the device and get back to home with 
    **[self.navigationController popToViewController:SomeViewController animated:YES]** code
it gives me the correct layout but when i push the view controller from landscape screen and rotate the device and pop the view controller with same code it gives me the landscape layout of the home screen.

Also there is something i found that on first case the 
    **- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation**" method is called but on the second case it is not being called. i am new to iphone/ipad development and i am not getting any idea to solve this issue.

--thanks in advance